# How can I place the table at right side of register text boxes

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table, alignment

[image]

Can I place the table using `<div>` tags?

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is take a piece of the image and just realign it. If you were hoping for code? Well, so were we; because we can't do anything with your image. If you were to replace that image with your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code (HTML, CSS), then we could give it a shot. But also: consider being more clear in your question. What table? Where you do you want to place it? We know nothing of your problem except for what you've told us, and you've effectively told us nothing in your question. Please, read the "*[ask]*" guidance, then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the register textboxes and the table in two different div tags and add style as `style="float:left;"` on register textboxes div and `style="float:right;"` on table div. The code should look something like this,

```
<div style="float:left;">
   <!-- code for register text boxes -->
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
   <!-- code for already registered students table -->
</div>
```